# Proof of the conjecture that the kernel is of dimension 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I already asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962971/prove-that-the-kernel-is-of-dimension-2) which has been answered. This question may seem very similar but the required matrix manipulations are probably very different here due to the addition of the matrix $\mathbf{P}$, which makes the problem more difficult.

"Experimentally", I found that the kernel (null space) of the following matrix is of dimension 2. I'd like to prove it, but haven't managed yet:
\begin{equation}
\text{for almost all } t>0,\quad \text{dim}\,\text{ker}\left(\mathbf{Q}_2\mathbf{Q}_1(t)-\mathbf{Q}_1(t)^{-1}\mathbf{Q}_2\right)\overbrace{=}^?\;2 
\end{equation}

where:

- $\mathbf{Q}_2$ is the identity matrix everywhere except in $(2n,2n)$:
  \begin{equation}
  \mathbf{Q}_2=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{I}_n & \mathbf{0}_n \\  \mathbf{0}_n & \mathbf{P}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1 & && \\ & \ddots && \\ & & 1& \\ &&& -1 \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{P}  \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2n\times2n}
  \end{equation}
  where $\mathbf{P}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is any invertible matrix.
- $\mathbf{Q}_1(t)$ is defined by:

\begin{equation}
\forall t>0,\quad\mathbf{Q}_1(t)=\begin{bmatrix}\textbf{cos}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) & \boldsymbol \Omega^{-1}\,\textbf{sin}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) \\  -\boldsymbol \Omega\,\textbf{sin}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) & \textbf{cos}(\boldsymbol \Omega t)\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2n\times2n}
\end{equation}
where (... sorry...):
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol\Omega=\begin{bmatrix} \omega_1 & & \\  & \ddots & \\  & & \omega_n  \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\quad \forall i\in\lbrace 1,\dots, n\rbrace, \omega_i>0
\end{equation}

and the four blocks are diagonal, for example:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{cos}(\boldsymbol\Omega t)=\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\omega_1t) & & \\  & \ddots & \\  & & \cos(\omega_n t)  \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}
\end{equation}

---

*Interesting properties of $\mathbf{Q}_1$ and $\mathbf{Q}_2$*:

Obviously, $\mathbf{Q}_2$ is invertible and $\mathbf{Q}_2=\mathbf{Q}_2^{-1}$.

Also, $\det(\mathbf{Q}_1)=1$ ($\omega_i>0$ and for proper $t>0$) and:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Q}_1(t)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\textbf{cos}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) & -\boldsymbol \Omega^{-1}\,\textbf{sin}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) \\  \boldsymbol \Omega\,\textbf{sin}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) & \textbf{cos}(\boldsymbol \Omega t)\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The initial equation can therefore also be written as:
\begin{equation}
\text{ker}\left(\mathbf{Q}_2\mathbf{Q}_1(t)-\mathbf{Q}_1(t)^{-1}\mathbf{Q}_2\right)=\text{ker}\left(\mathbf{Q}_2\mathbf{Q}_1(t)\mathbf{Q}_2\mathbf{Q}_1(t)-\mathbf{1}_{2n}\right)
\end{equation}

So another way of solving the problem is to prove that 1 is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf{Q}_2\mathbf{Q}_1(t)\mathbf{Q}_2\mathbf{Q}_1(t)$ with a multiplicity of 2. But I'm not sure this helps...

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$\begin{split}A&=Q_2Q_1-{Q_1}^{-1}Q_2 \\ &=\begin{pmatrix}0&\Omega ^{-1}\sin(\Omega t)(I+P^{-1}DP)\\-(P^{-1}DP+I)\Omega\sin(\Omega t)&P^{-1}DP\cos(\Omega t)-\cos(\Omega t)P^{-1}DP\end{pmatrix}\end{split}$$ 
Then $$\begin{split}\phi(x)&=\pm\det(A-xI)\\
&=\det\bigg[-(P^{-1}DP+I)\sin(\Omega t)^2(I+P^{-1}DP) \\ &+x(P^{-1}DP\cos(\Omega t)-\cos(\Omega t)P^{-1}DP)-x^2I\bigg] \\
&=\det(-U+xV-x^2I) \end{split}$$

$\phi(0)=\det(-U)=0$ (because $I+P^{-1}DP$ is not invertible). 
Now 
$$\begin{split}\phi'(0)&=-\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adjoint}(U)V) \\ 
&=-\operatorname{tr}\bigg((\operatorname{adjoint}((P^{-1}DP+I)\sin(\Omega t)^2(I+P^{-1}DP)) \\ &\times (P^{-1}DP\cos(\Omega t)-\cos(\Omega t)P^{-1}DP)\bigg)
\end{split}$$

After a change of basis , we may assume $P^{-1}DP=\operatorname{diag}(1,\cdots,1,-1)$, $$S=\operatorname{adjoint}(\sin(\Omega t)^{2})=[s_{i,j}],C=\cos(\Omega t)=[c_{i,j}]$$

Then $\operatorname{adjoint}(U)=2^{2n-2}s_{n,n}E_{n,n}$ and consequently (if $V=[v_{i,j}]$), $$\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adjoint}(U)V)=2^{2n-2}s_{n,n}v_{n,n}.$$ Yet $v_{n,n}=-c_{n,n}+c_{n,n}=0$. Thus $\phi'(0)=0$  and $x=0$ is (at least) a double eigenvalue.

We consider the generic case (with respect to $\Omega,P,t$ and not only $t$). To see that, generically, $\dim(\ker(A))$ is exactly $2$, it suffices to give an instance, in dimension $n$, where $A$ is diagonalizable and $0$ is an eigenvalue with exactly the multiplicity $2$. It is not difficult (take $P=I_n,...$) - For a rigorous reasoning, you must use the Zariski's topology-.

Comment: Very interesting, I'd never have found that. I'll enter into details tomorrow. What is $E_{n,n}$? Are you summing over $n$? Funnily enough last night I slept in an inn called... the White Wolf Inn!

Comment: @ anderstood , $E_{i,j}$ is the $n\times n$ matrix, the entries of which are $0$, except the $(i,j)$ entry that is $1$. About your inn, I think that you were in the mountains !

Comment: OK so I read your answer carefully. First of all, thank you and congrats for having found this approach. Something I'm not totally comfortable with: "after a change of basis, we may assume ...". I'm not sure if this is valid, because if we had changed the basis before, we would not have found something so "simple". Also, this does not change anything to the proof but I think $\text{adjoint}(U)=2^{4n-2}...$ instead of $2^{2n-2}$.

Comment: For the reciprocal, I'm lost: how could an example prove that dim(ker($A$)) is no greater than 2, but not prove that is no smaller than 2? (the answer must be in Zariski's topology but I've never heard about it and it is not so clear to me).

Comment: @ anderstood  1. with my change of basis, $P^{-1}DP$ becomes $D$ and $\Omega$ becomes $P\Omega P^{-1}$ ; I can do that because the fact that $\Omega$ is diagonal is useless. I do not see any mistake in my calculation of $adjoint(U)$.  2. The end of my post is not at all a converse. Always $x=0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $\geq 2$. In particular $dim(\ker(A))=1$ or $2$ or more. Moreover, generically, $dim(\ker(A))=2$  because generically $discrim(A-xI,x)$ and $\phi'''(0)$ are not identically $0$.

Comment: In the end of my previous comment, read "$discrim(\det(A-xI),x))$". To show that, it suffices to find an instance of $P,\Omega,t$ satisfying the conditions given in my answer. Using algebraic topology, the conclusion, about genericity follows, but I do not want to write the details.

Comment: 1. Ok, "the fact that $\Omega$ is diagonal is useless" was what I was missing. And your calculation is correct. 2. Sure, I misused the word. Would you agree to continue on the chat later this week? I have some "extensions" to the question.

Comment: @ anderstood , if you have some other question, then post it on the forum in the form of another question.

Comment: I was afraid of flooding SE with the same type of question, but there it is: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976987/proof-of-the-conjecture-that-the-kernel-is-of-dimension-2-extended. I did not manage to extend your demonstration because $A$ does not have the same structure with a 0 block.