# Proof of the conjecture that the kernel is of dimension 2, extended

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Pursuing my research, I am now looking for a proof of an extension of the problem proposed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964373/proof-of-the-conjecture-that-the-kernel-is-of-dimension-2) and answered. It's an extension in the sense that I'm now considering two different $t_1$ and $t_2$. The "conjecture" still stands though.

"Experimentally", I found that the kernel (null space) of the following matrix is of dimension 2. I'd like to prove it, but haven't managed yet:
\begin{equation}
\text{for almost all } t_1>0,\quad \text{dim}\,\text{ker}\left(\mathbf{Q}_2\mathbf{Q}_1(t_1)-\mathbf{Q}_1(t_2)^{-1}\mathbf{Q}_2\right)\overbrace{=}^?\;2 
\end{equation} where $t_2$ is chosen such that $$\text{det}\left(\mathbf{Q}_2\mathbf{Q}_1(t_1)-\mathbf{Q}_1(t_2)^{-1}\mathbf{Q}_2\right)=0$$
We assume that such a $t_2$ exist.
where:

- $\mathbf{Q}_2$ is the following matrix:
  \begin{equation}
  \mathbf{Q}_2=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{I}_n & \mathbf{0}_n \\  \mathbf{0}_n & \mathbf{P}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1 & && \\ & \ddots && \\ & & 1& \\ &&& -1 \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{P}  \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2n\times2n}
  \end{equation}
  where $\mathbf{P}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is any invertible matrix.
- $\mathbf{Q}_1(t)$ is defined by:

\begin{equation}
\forall t>0,\quad\mathbf{Q}_1(t)=\begin{bmatrix}\textbf{cos}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) & \boldsymbol \Omega^{-1}\,\textbf{sin}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) \\  -\boldsymbol \Omega\,\textbf{sin}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) & \textbf{cos}(\boldsymbol \Omega t)\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2n\times2n}
\end{equation}
and:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol\Omega=\begin{bmatrix} \omega_1 & & \\  & \ddots & \\  & & \omega_n  \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\quad \forall i\in\lbrace 1,\dots, n\rbrace, \omega_i>0
\end{equation}

and the four blocks are diagonal, for example:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{cos}(\boldsymbol\Omega t)=\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\omega_1t) & & \\  & \ddots & \\  & & \cos(\omega_n t)  \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}
\end{equation}

---

*Interesting properties of $\mathbf{Q}_1$ and $\mathbf{Q}_2$*:

Obviously, $\mathbf{Q}_2$ is invertible and $\mathbf{Q}_2=\mathbf{Q}_2^{-1}$.

Also, $\det(\mathbf{Q}_1)=1$ ($\omega_i>0$ and for proper $t>0$) and:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Q}_1(t)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\textbf{cos}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) & -\boldsymbol \Omega^{-1}\,\textbf{sin}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) \\  \boldsymbol \Omega\,\textbf{sin}(\boldsymbol \Omega t) & \textbf{cos}(\boldsymbol \Omega t)\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

---

*Why I'm not able to extend [loup blanc's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/971763/36578) to the present problem with two different $t_1$ and $t_2$.*

Let's define $A:=\mathbf{Q}_2\mathbf{Q}_1(t_1)-\mathbf{Q}_1(t_2)^{-1}\mathbf{Q}_2$ and $\phi(x):=\det(A-xI)$. The problem is to prove that $0$ is a zero of $\phi$ with multiplicity 2. By definition of $t_2$, $\phi(0)=\det(A)=0$. So I now have to prove that $\phi'(0)=0$ (and then than $\dim(\ker(A))\leqslant 2$).

$\phi'(0)=-\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adjoint}(A))$ from Jacobi's formula.

The calculation of $A$ gives:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} c_1-c_2 & \Omega^{-1}s_1+\Omega^{-1}s_2 P^{-1}DP \\ -P^{-1}DP\Omega s_1-\Omega s_2 & P^{-1}DPc_1-c_2P^{-1}DP\end{bmatrix}$$
where $c_i=\textbf{cos}(\Omega t_i)$, $s_i=\textbf{sin}(\Omega t_i)$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,\dots,1,-1)$.

This time, the determinant of $A$ is harder to calculate because the upper-left block is non-zero. So I'm stuck with proving that $\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adjoint}(A))=0$. I also tried to apply things such as $A\operatorname{adjoint}(A)=\det(A)I$ but there is no mystery: I have to use the properties of $A$, and that's what I'm not managing to do.

**EDIT** I still did not manage to prove that for $t_1,t_2$ such that $\det(Q_2Q_1(t_2)Q_2Q_1(t_1)-I_{2n})=0$,  $\dim(\ker(Q_2Q_1(t_2)Q_2Q_1(t_1)-I_{2n})=2$. I though of proving it by induction but I am still stuck with the inductive step. Do you think this is a good idea? Would you have some relevant references to help me?